# Validation in excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, validation

Suppose I have a value in an excel cell A5.Let it be 1.3.And then I have cells in the same column below the cell A5 like A6,A7,A8...with some value in it.

Is there any validation method in Java that when I change the value from 1.3 to 1.4 or some other value, all the values in the cells A6,A7,A8 .. gets changed to 1.4 that is becomes equal to A5 ?

Thanks for your answers beforehand.

Comment: Why would you need JAVA for that? It doesn't seem like there would be a problem to implement this with some simple formulas.

Comment: @J.Males   : I need to generate the excel sheet through java.Well bear me..am new to this..

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be that you just insert the formulas in the cells through JAVA.

For example, in Excel you want to be a cell the total of two other cells:

```
C5: =A1+A2
```

If you for example use the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), you can use the [setCellFormula](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#setCellFormula%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
String formula = "=A1+A2";
cell.setCellFormula(formula);
```

[Here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-write-to-an-excel-file-using-poi.html) is a little example of how to create the cell objects an how to use the apache POI